# MS Access Calculating date differences if Dates are Short Text

Tags: ms-access

Is is possible in a Table to Calculate differences between Dates if the Value in the field is considered "short text"?

I am working to convert an Excel macro database into Access one and I have imported the data from the Excel file into an Access Table.

however i realized 2 feilds that count up until closure are now just fixed numbers but need to add up as each day passes until closure

when i imported the Dates became Short Text.

is there an expression that would handle this situation?
Each record has a serialized non repeating ID number seperate from access as well.

Dates I have are
OfficialissuanceDate,
DatePlanSubmitted,
DatePlanCompletedSubmitted,
DateClosed,

I need 2 calculations that increments daily when DateplanSubmitted and DatePlanCompletedSubmitted are null
Both comparing to OfficialIssuanceDate. then stop counting when they are no longer null. (have a date in updated to the record) and retain the value.

I have tried to Google calculating Dates but i get DateDiff function which doesnt appear to work. I've used Access and taken a class on it but never really made a new DB from scratch

Comment: Convert fields to date/time type or use CDate() function to convert text to actual date value. "Doesn't appear to work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? What do you mean by "count up until closure"? Edit question to show sample data as formatted text (don't use image).

Comment: My result is "#Type!" but this is was using simple expression [Date Closed] - [Date Opened]. By "Counting up until closure" as each day passes if we open the table the value would increase by 1 until a date issue is closed.  essentially its just to track how our Response times are for Issues.

Comment: Going into my table in Design view and changing it the fields to Date/Time corrected the math, i compared the values to the original saved data from Excel and it matches

Comment: Do you mean you want the date difference to calculate with current date when Date Closed is null? `Nz([Date Closed], Date()) - [Date Opened]`. BTW, advise not to use space in field names nor punctuation/special characters.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I Recognize now that what I put in is much to simplle and will not put a value in UNTIL there's a date closed. So Yes i would need to figure out how to Count dates when there are null fields.

Comment: I have edited the post to further clarify the fieldnames

Comment: I tried "Nz([Date Closed], Date()) - [Date Opened]" in the expression and it said that this formula can not be used in a calculated column. what should i change the data type to?

Comment: Nz() is not available in table Calculated type. Have to do calc in query or textbox. Or use `IIf(IsNull([DateClosed), Date(), [DateClosed]) - [DateOpened]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in a text field are not actual dates, just strings of characters. A Date/Time field stores value as a double number then displays in a date structure - "dd/mm/yyyy" is Access default structure.

Sometimes Access will do implicit conversion of data but not in this case. Either change field type to Date/Time or do conversion with CDate() function. However, you will find that conversion functions error with Null input.

Arithmetic operation with Date/Time field type is possible. However, arithmetic when any term is null returns Null so have to deal with that. One way uses Nz() function: `Nz([DateClosed], Date()) - [DateOpened]`. Unfortunately, Nz() is not available in table Calculated field type, so do that calc in query or textbox. Most developers avoid table Calculated field type. If you really want to use, expression would have to be: `IIf(IsNull([DateClosed), Date(), [DateClosed]) - [DateOpened]`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! although the expression works i am going to take everyones advice and build it into an update query, I was trying to rebuild the existing database knowing theres records that need to be appended so i will work the date calculation query into an update query after i append the table for new records.

Comment: I set up an update query to test updating the dates and i tried the following: Nz([Maindata].[LTCMPlanSubmitted], Now()-[Maindata].[LTCMPlanSubmitted]) and ALSO Nz([Maindata].[LTCMPlanSubmitted], DateDiff("d",Now(),[Maindata].[LTCMPlanSubmitted])) and both fill the column with data with our error but the result is both a Date when it needs to be a number. when i changed the type in the field of the table to Number it produces an Error saying it failed to update 583 fields for various reasons. then the column is blank as a result. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Ha! got it figured out its adding correctly now! thank you

Comment: I would NOT advise to save these calculated results to table. Who is 'everyone'?